# Actionscript add object to stage from array whats from library

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

I try import from library to a array and after place objectsd from array to stage.
I'm new in flash and  i would make a dress up game for my girlfriend.

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

var polc1Ar:Array = new Array();
inditasFu();

function inditasFu(){
    behivas();
    rakdkiFu();
}

function behivas(){
    for (var i=1; i!=3; i++) {
        classRef:getDefinitionByName("Symbol" + i.toString()) = new getDefinitionByName("Symbol" + i.toString() as MovieClip)();
        var classRef:Symbol1 = new Symbol1();
        polc1Ar.push(classRef)
        addChild(polc1Ar[0]);
        }
}

function rakdkiFu (){
    for (var i=0; i!=polc1Ar.length; i++) {
        var celTargy:Bitmap = polc1Ar[i] as Bitmap ;
        this.addChild(celTargy);
        celTargy.x = 25*i;
        celTargy.y = 45*i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if there are `Symbol1, Symbol2, and Symbol3` exported as Classes in your library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of Syntax errors in your code.  Change all of your code to:

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.BitmapData;

var polc1Ar:Array = new Array();
inditasFu();

function inditasFu(){
    behivas();
    rakdkiFu();
}

function behivas(){
    for (var i=1; i!=3; i++) {
        var ClassRef:Class = getDefinitionByName("Symbol" + i.toString()) as Class;
        var classRef = new ClassRef();
        polc1Ar.push(classRef)
        addChild(polc1Ar[0]);
        }
}

function rakdkiFu (){
    for (var i=0; i!=polc1Ar.length; i++) {
        var bmpData = new BitmapData(polc1Ar[i].width, polc1Ar[i].height);
        bmpData.draw(polc1Ar[i]);
        var celTargy:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmpData);
        this.addChild(celTargy);
        celTargy.x = 25*i;
        celTargy.y = 45*i;
    }
}
```

**[1]** You cannot execute 'MovieClip as Bitmap' so I used `Bitmap.draw()` because a MovieClip *is* an `IBitmapDrawable`.

**[2]** You must create a class with `getDefinitionByName`, you cannot just create the MovieClip directly, unless you were to create very messy code.  Basically, the Syntax was wrong for it.

**[3]** Note that this will only work if you have three **Library Clips** with **Exported Class Names** named *Symbol1, Symbol2, and Symbol3.*